# Analysing the solution of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm currently dealing with the following differential equation:

$\frac{db}{dt}(t) = f(a(t)) - \gamma b(t)$,

with $f(a) = \frac{a^4}{2^4+a^4}$, a periodic function $a(t)$ and a decay rate $\gamma$.

One can show that the soultion $b(t)$ is also a periodic function.

When I solve this differential equation numerically, I get the result that the values of the solution $b(t)$ averaged over a period scale with the factor $\gamma$ which is also the decay rate.

My question:
Can one prove that the average of $b(t)$ directly scales with $\gamma$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you may verify that the stationary solution to your ODE is given by
$$ b(t) = \int_{-\infty}^t f(a(s)) \; e^{\gamma (s-t)} \; ds =\int_{-\infty}^0 f(a(t+s)) \; e^{\gamma s} \; ds $$
If $T$ is the period and $m = \int_0^T f(a(t)) \; dt$ then taking the $t$-integral first (and using the 2nd formula):
$$ \int_0^T b(t) \; dt = \int_{-\infty}^0 m \; e^{\gamma s} \; ds = \frac{m}{\gamma}$$
thus also giving you what the average is in terms of the average of the forcing term.

As is seen from the last expression the solution is indeed periodic with the same period as $f(a(t))$. Note that if for some reason one already knows that the solution is periodic then you may also simply integrate the two sides of the ode, to get the same conclusion without the explicit form for the solution:
$$ 0 = b(T)-b(0)=\int_0^T \dot{b}(t)\; dt= \int_0^T f(a(t))dt + \gamma \int_0^T b(t) \; dt = m + \gamma \int_0^T b(t)) dt$$

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I was looking for!

Comment: Do you know how to prove that the solution $b(t)$ is a periodic function at all?

Comment: Yes, that follows from the second expression. Substituting $t+T$ for $t$ leaves the integral invariant. Note that the first expression is used to prove that it is the solution. The second (obtained by a simple substitution) to deduce the various periodic properties.

Comment: I've got a problem that is related to this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1943981/simplifying-a-system-of-differential-equations?
Do you perhaps know how that works, too?

Comment: @Peter123 I had a look but no, I don't really have any good ideas. I think it depends upon constants and what 'qualitative' behaviour you want to preserve.